# Why isn't my MySQL data being displayed in my table?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

Why is my MySQL data not being displayed in my table?  Everything seems to work fine except that my data (which is a list of bird names and such) isn't showing up.  I need some fresh eyes who can see where my mistake is, and yes I know that there are probably easier ways to do this, but this is what is required for my assignment, so please don't offer other ways to do this.  All I need is help getting my data to populate in the HTML table.   My PHP code is below:

PHP Code

```
<?php
    $pageTitle = 'Mod06 Pagination| Jason McCoy ';
    include('includes/header.inc.php');
    include ('includes/db_connect.inc.php');

    $display = 8;

    // Determine how many pages there are...

    if (isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])) { // Already been determined.
        $pages = $_GET['pages'];
    } else { 
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(birdID) FROM birds";
        $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        $row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
        $records = $row[0];
    }

    // Calculate the number of pages...

    if ($records > $display) { 
        $pages = ceil($records/$display);
    } else {
        $pages = 1;
    }

    // Determine where in the database to start returning results...

    if (isset($_GET['s']) && is_numeric($_GET['s'])) {
        $start = $_GET['s'];
    } else {
        $start = 0;
    }

    // Sort the columns 
    // Default is birdID

        $sortDefault = 'birdID';

        // Create an array for the columns

        $sortColumns = array('birdID', 'nameGeneral', 'nameSpecific', 'populationTrend');

        // Define sortable query ASC DESC

        $sort =  (isset($_GET['sort'])) && in_array($_GET['sort'], $sortColumns) ? $_GET['sort']: $sortDefault;
        $order = (isset($_GET['order']) && strcasecmp($_GET['order'], 'DESC') == 0) ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

        // Run the query 

    $query = "SELECT birdID, nameGeneral, nameSpecific, populationTrend FROM birds ORDER BY $order LIMIT $start, $display";
    $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);       
?>

    <!-- Table header: -->
    <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="80%">
        <tr>
            <th><a href='index.php?sort=birdID&order=<?php echo $order == 'DESC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC' ?>'>Bird<?
                            if($_GET["order"]=="ASC" && $_GET["sort"]=="birdID"){
                                echo '<img src="images/downArrow.jpg" id="birdASC" name="birdASC" style="margin:-15px 0 0 13px;" width="18px" height="18px">';
                            } else {
                    echo '<img src="images/upArrow.jpg" id="birdDESC" name="birdDESC" style="margin:-15px 0 0 13px;" width="18px" height="18px">';
                }?></a></th>
            <th><a href='index.php?sort=nameGeneral&order=<?php echo $order == 'DESC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC' ?>'>General Name<?
                            if($_GET["order"]=="ASC" && $_GET["sort"]=="nameGeneral"){
                                echo '<img src="images/downArrow.jpg" id="nameGeneralASC" name="nameGeneralASC" style="margin:-15px 0 0 13px;" width="18px" height="18px">';
                            } else {
                    echo '<img src="images/upArrow.jpg" id="nameGeneralDESC" name="birdDESC" style="margin:-15px 0 0 13px;" width="18px" height="18px">';
                }?></a></th>
            <th><a href='index.php?sort=nameSpecific&order=<?php echo $order == 'DESC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC' ?>'>Name Specific<?
                            if($_GET["order"]=="ASC" && $_GET["sort"]=="nameSpecific"){
                                echo '<img src="images/downArrow.jpg" id="nameSpecificASC" name="nameSpecificASC" style="margin:-15px 0 0 13px;" width="18px" height="18px">';
                            } else {
                    echo '<img src="images/upArrow.jpg" id="nameSpecificDESC" name="birdDESC" style="margin:-15px 0 0 13px;" width="18px" height="18px">';
                }?></a></th>
            <th><a href='index.php?sort=populationTrend&order=<?php echo $order == 'DESC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC' ?>'>Population Trend<?
                            if($_GET["order"]=="ASC" && $_GET["sort"]=="populationTrend"){
                                echo '<img src="images/downArrow.jpg" id="populationTrendASC" name="populationTrendASC" style="margin:-15px 0 0 13px;" width="18px" height="18px">';
                            } else {
                    echo '<img src="images/upArrow.jpg" id="populationTrendDESC" name="birdDESC" style="margin:-15px 0 0 13px;" width="18px" height="18px">';
                }?></a></th>
        </tr>
<?php

    // Display the database results in the table...

    while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<tr>
            <td align="left">$row[birdID]</td>
            <td align="left">$row[nameGeneral]</td>
            <td align="left">$row[nameSpecific]</td>
            <td align="left">$row[populationTrend]</td>
         <tr>';
    } 

    echo '</table>';    
    mysqli_close($dbc);

    // Make the links to other pages, if necessary.
    if ($pages > 1) {
        echo '<br /><p>';
        $currentPage = ($start/$display) + 1;
    // If it's not the first page, make a Previous button:
    if ($currentPage != 1) {
        echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&pages=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">Previous</a> ';
    }
    // Make all the numbered pages:
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        if ($i != $currentPage) {
            echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&pages=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
        } else {
            echo $i . ' ';
        }
    } // End of FOR loop.

    // If it's not the last page, make a Next button:
    if ($currentPage != $pages) {
        echo '<a href="index.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&pages=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">Next</a>';
    }

    echo '</p>'; 

} 

    include('includes/footer.inc.php');
?>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this one `$row[birdID]` to `$row['birdID']`  for all, you missed `''`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but that doesn't work, it returns an error

Comment: Here is a link to the page if you want to see what is displayed currently:  http://www.jasonkmccoy.com/AB-Tech/web250/Mod06/McCoy_mod06/index.php?sort=nameSpecific&order=ASC   I got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/jkm1972/public_html/AB-Tech/web250/Mod06/McCoy_mod06/index.php on line 92

Answer (score 0):

use `"` inside echo like this, you have used `'` because of that the value from database is not displayed.

```
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>
        <td align=\"left\">$row[birdID]</td>
        <td align=\"left\">$row[nameGeneral]</td>
        <td align=\"left\">$row[nameSpecific]</td>
        <td align=\"left\">$row[populationTrend]</td>
     <tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if a bit concise, typing from a phone...

'$row[birdID]'

and the other parts should be properly rewritten as:

'$row['birdID']'

as birdID is a string, not a variable name.

Though PHP uses this as a string, if there is no variable with that name in the current scope.

> Always use quotes around a string literal array index. For example, $foo['bar'] is
>   correct, while $foo[bar] is not. But why? It is common to encounter this kind of
>   syntax in old scripts

from the PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

**EDIT** somebody pointed out the single quotes used in echo too, that is a problem too. with single quotes, PHP will not interpret the content of the string, whereas with double quotes, PHP will parsde it, and use the values properly.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but what you suggested didn't work.

Comment: I was just thinking - didn't MySQL use **only** lowercase table names and column names? Try it with 'birdid' instead of 'birdID', and so on. Sadly, I don't have a MySQL to test this right now.

Also, try running the query itself in MySQL workbench or PHPMyAdmin - whichever you have...

Comment: I have the data displaying properly now but the sorting isn't working